# getting current background transfer tasks returns empty list on UWP

Tags: download, background, uwp, task, transfer

I use the background transfer tasks to download files in my UWP c# application. When the app is closed and reopen, we normally can discover the pending tasks with the function `GetCurrentDownloadsAsync`.

Unfortunately, it returns always an empty list even if the task is not completed.
It did not manage to compile the https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer sample to see if the behavior is the same.

Does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, it returns always an empty list even if the task is not completed

By testing on my side I cannot reproduce your issue. I tested with the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer), after closed with one task still in progress, and then reopen, the count of    `BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync()` will return to one correctly. Here is the testing result:
[image]

My testing environment is OS build 15063. Please also tried to test the official sample on your side. And please ensure that you "closed and reopen" the app, not uninstall since when an app is uninstalled any current or persisted Background Transfer operations associated with it are cleaned up. More details please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/background-transfers).

If you still have issues, please upload a minimal reproduced project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I do not manage to build the sample: I have this issue: ppData\Local\Temp\.NETCore,Version=v5.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,20,4,26): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: ok i managed to build it and the GetCurrentDownloadsAsync returns a non-empty list. I will put a part of my work source code.